# Justify text in memoir class margintable environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, marginpar

In page 181 of `texdoc memoir`,

> The `marginfigure` and `margintable` environments can of course be adjusted using `\setfloatadjustment`, default
>
> ```
> \setfloatadjustment{marginfigure}{\centering}
> \setfloatadjustment{margintable}{\centering}
> ```

The default alignment is `\centering`. I want to justify the text of a `margintable`. But I don't know what the command for explicit justification, so I tried the following

```
\setfloatadjustment{margintable}{\raggedright}
```

Of course that is only flushed to the left, with a ragged right edge. How do I justify the text inside a `margintable` environment of the `memoir` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [ragged2e](http://ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package and its `\justifying` macro.

EDIT: I should have guessed that `memoir` provides its own macro for the task: `\flushleftright`.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Variant A
% \usepackage{ragged2e}
% \setfloatadjustment{marginfigure}{\justifying}

% Variant B
\setfloatadjustment{marginfigure}{\flushleftright}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{marginfigure}
\lipsum[1]
\end{marginfigure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: it's nice to know that this can be done, but ragged was almost certainly used for a reason.  just compare the appearance of the main text and the margin block, and you'll understand why.  if your content really does naturally come out with good spacing in a justified environment, go with it, but look at the output with a critical eye before "freezing" it.  that may mean resetting individual margin blocks selectively.